# Invalid syntax for a lambda function with if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I would like a way to delete the part of a string before a specified character inside a dataframe column.

In my df column, I have strings with 1 or 2 commas. For the rows where there are 2 commas, I want to remove everything up to and including the first comma. I've tried the following lambda function:

```
df.column.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1:] if x.str.count(',') == 2 else x)
```

but I'm receiving an attribute error:

'str' object has no attribute 'str'

Even though I've already converted the column to str using

```
df.column = df.column.astype(str)
```

Comment: `x` is already a `str`, and do not have that attributte, remove it: `df.column.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[1:] if x.count(',') == 2 else x)`

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple. Thanks so much!

Comment: Thanks again for the answer, but this changed the edited values into a list, which made the column series have unique values which aren't really unique. 

e.g. "x, y, z" became "['y', 'z']" instead of just "y, z"

I've tried to convert them again using astype(str) and also changing to a new type using astype('category'), but that still didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will using `np.where`

```
df.column=np.where(df.column.str.count(',')==2,df.column.str.split(',',n=1).str[-1],df.column)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It took me a while to understand your response and the error that came with it ("operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1432,) (1432,) (23,)". I tried looking into it, but I'm not able to find out where the 23 shape is coming from.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! This worked perfectly!!
I'm guessing the issue was that it was storing x as a series based on the split, as opposed to the original. Thanks again!